# Remove ActionBar Top Heading in XamarinForms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have implemented a dashboard with Navigation Drawer in Xamarin Forms. I want to Remove the Blue part in the below image and move the toggle button to my design. Please help
[image]

I have implemented navigation Drawer/Flyout as follows using Shell Flyout

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

I tried using the above line of code from another stack overflow question but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

I think for `Shell` is a bug to hide this ActionBar. I have a project in Shell and I tried everything to hide it, but nothing worked. So I just deal with it:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="MyTitle" Order="Primary"/>
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="img1.png" Order="Primary"/>
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="img2.png" Order="Primary"/>
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="img3.png" Order="Primary"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

If you want, you can remove your actionBar and use this ActionBar of Shell editing it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the screenshot, you have two flyout page.

1. If you use the Shell template, it has a flyout page by default when you set the `FlyoutDisplayOptions` to `AsMultipleItems`.

   Shell flyout: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout
2. If you only want a flyout without Shell template, a east way is to use `FlyoutPage`.

   Please note, if you use the `NavigationPage` in your App.xaml.cs, it would show the bar like below. So do not use it when you use the Flyoutpage.

   ```
     MainPage =  new NavigationPage(new Flyoutpage());
   ```

   FlyoutPage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage

Answer (score 2):

Use `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"` Inside Content Page Will Work
`Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = true;` in button click  Will open Drawer. This answer was Found in

### https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/349760/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-on-xamarin-forms-when-u.html